# Upgrade to specific distribution with do-release-upgrade?

Tags: upgrade

I have Ubuntu precise running on a VPS (server). I am connected with SSH and would like to upgrade to Ubuntu trusty.

I do not want the newest release. Changing `/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` to "normal" causes the `do-release-upgrade` shell script to select the next release (*12.10*), not *13.x*. Selecting LTS goes straight to *14.x*. How do I specify *13.x* release?

Would I have to manually change the `/apt/sources.list` to point to trusty and then do a `dist-upgrade`? I prefer to do it with the `do-release-upgrade` script, but can't figure out how.

Comment: "Would I have to manually change the /apt/sources.list to point to trusty and then do a dist-upgrade?" This is not advisable or supported by Ubuntu.

Comment: Also, 14.04 is called `trusty`.

Answer (score 2):

### 14.04 *is* the next LTS release after 12.04.

It's what you want on a server. They last for five years after release (rather than nine months).

The only upgrade path that supports skipping versions is the LTS→LTS one. You cannot jump from 12.04 to 13.x. Neither would you want to; **both 13.x releases have been dead for some time**.

The latest LTS is currently 14.04 and the latest non-LTS is 15.04. The next LTS will probably be 16.04. You can read more about the [Ubuntu Releases](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) and see when support periods run out.